# Is is safe to modify readonly NSData via pointer address?

Tags: ios, nsdata, xor

I want to perform an XOR operation for NSData as below, is it safe to modify an readonly NSData like this (non ARC)? I have tried, it did work.

```
    @implementation NSData (Additions)

    - (void)xorWithByteKey:(Byte)keyByte
    {
        char *curDataPtr = (char *)self.bytes;

        for (int x = 0; x < self.length; x++)
        {
            *curDataPtr = *curDataPtr ^ keyByte;
            curDataPtr++;
        }
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a look at [CFData source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFData.c) what you are doing *seems* safe. I had a quick search for references to `_bytes` (which is what you are accessing directly) and nothing jumped at me.

Though do you really want to take the risk of relying on such an implementation detail? Is it too costly in your code to go via an NSMutableData copy of your data and modify that instead?

As in this category (warning, untested):

```
@interface NSData (xoring)
- (NSData *) xorWithByteKey: (Byte) b ;
@end

@implementation NSData (xoring)

- (NSData *) xorWithByteKey: (Byte) b {

   NSMutableData * copy = [self mutableCopy] ;

   char *p = (char *)copy.bytes;

   for (NSUInteger i = 0, length = copy.length ; i < length; ++i) {
        Byte c = *p ;
        c ^= b ;
        *p++ = c ;
    }
    return copy ;
}
```

@end

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to say that this is an absolutely stupid idea and will cause you all kind of trouble. For starters, guess what happens if you have an original NSData object and copied it, and then try this nonsense (if it doesn't crash in the first place). I think any damage caused by this would fall into the category of "deliberate" which means you could be held personally responsible.